# RestTemplate: how to send multipart?

Tags: java, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I need to send request. It looks like this cURL request:

```
 curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/attachments'
--form 'data=@path/to/file/6C233C5F-B60D-41CA-86ED-A43C51FD7EED.png'
```

If to convert it to IDEA http request, it shall look like here:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/attachments
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=WebAppBoundary

--WebAppBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"; filename="6C233C5F-B60D-41CA-86ED-A43C51FD7EED.png"

< path/to/file/6C233C5F-B60D-41CA-86ED-A43C51FD7EED.png
--WebAppBoundary--
```

Ok, but I need to send it with `restTemplate`. And it's desirable to use `byte[]` instead of file path.
Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code fragment

```
        HttpEntity<?> entity;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        Object requestBody;
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        requestBody = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedData);

        entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);

        ResponseEntity response = getRestTemplate().exchange(
                serviceURL,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                entity,
                String.class
        );
```

You can read file content to byte array and send it the same way.